# Python - identical code, identical pc's; but only 1 gets TypeError: (pywintypes.datetime)

Tags: python, typeerror, python-datetime

I have a Python script that I wrote recently and it runs perfectly on one pc, but not on another pc. I have verified that both machines have the exact same version of Python (3.6.0) and the exact same verion of Anaconda (4.3.1 64-Bit)

The code:

```
import requests
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com.client #as win32
import datetime
import os
import re
import pywintypes
import time


# First I obtain data from a given webpage using the 'requests' library
# .. and write it to file

text_file.write(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', result.text))

# Next, I parse the text file using  the below:  
    if 'startDate' in line:
        str = line
        str = str.replace('"','')
        str = str.replace(':','')
        str = str.replace('{','')
        str = str.replace('}','')
        str = str.replace('[','')
        str = str.replace(']','')
        str = str.replace('startDate','')
        str = str.replace("\n","")
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str)/1000.0)
        str = dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y" + " %H:%M:%S %p")
        xlSht.Cells(i,6).Value = str
        #xlSht.Cells(i,6).Value = dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y")  + " %I:%M:%S %p")
        xlSht.Cells(i,6).NumberFormat = "[$-409]mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM;@"    

# Line that is parsed: "starDate":1528231802193},

# I then parse the field which will be compared to the above:

    if '"date":{"endDate":' in line: # Column U
        str = line
        str = str.replace('"','')
        str = str.replace(':','')
        str = str.replace('{','')
        str = str.replace('}','')
        str = str.replace('[','')
        str = str.replace(']','')
        str = str.replace('endDate','')
        str = str.replace("\n","")
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str)/1000.0)
        xlSht.Cells(i,21).Value = dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y" + " %H:%M:%S %p") 
        xlSht.Cells(i,21).NumberFormat = "[$-409]m/d/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM;@"

# Line that is parsed: "endDate":1528231801083},



# Finally I compare the two values within excel

xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = 1
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
xlSht = xlWb.Worksheets(1)


x = 2
while len(xlSht.Cells(x,1).Text) > 0: 
    if xlSht.Cells(x,6).Value < xlSht.Cells(x,21).Value:
        xlSht.Cells(x,6).Value = xlSht.Cells(x,21).Value
    x += 1

# Example: xlSht.Cells(6, 1).Value = 06/07/18 10:45:56 AM
# Example: xlSht.Cells(x, 21).Value = 6/5/18 10:45:56 AM
```

Now while it runs on my machine without a hitch, when I try and run it on another another pc I get the below error

```
line 1428, in <module>...
if xlSht.Cells(x,6).Value < xlSht.Cells(x,21).Value:   

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'pywintypes.datetime and 
'float'
```

I am perplexed how this is possible. Any solutions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Seriously? The operator in the error message is `','`?

Comment: Why all the extra imports? If you cut down your example code to just what's needed for the example code, it will be easier to understand your problem.  Further, there's a decent chance you'll get a better understanding of the problem yourself.

Comment: I don't think this is code you actually ran or an error message you actually received. Please post an actual error message and code that actually produces the error message when run, and please copy-paste, rather than retyping either the code or the error message.

Comment: The overall code is 1500+ lines, I just trimmed it down to what I thought was relevant. Also, every single library is used within my code.

Comment: The only `>` that you have in your code compares an int and an int. The error message that you included was not produced by this code. Please post the _complete_ error message.

Comment: When you trim the code (and you definitely should do that), test to see if the problem still occurs...

Comment: The posted code wouldn't work at all since `xlSht` is undefined. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also regarding the comments at the end of code: check `xlSht.Cells(2, 1)`, `xlSht.Cells(2, 6)`, `xlSht.Cells(2, 21)`. Regarding last edit which is line 1428?

Comment: If you are working with Excel, see if both pc's have the same decimal separator (`.` or `,`). Also remember that Excel uses mostly American English when receiving data from these kinds of calls, so beware of the MM-DD-YYYY format for dates.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're importing data from Excel.  In which case the likely problem is that you're comparing two fields which are of different types.  I.e. exactly what the error is telling you. Try changing the source data.

Putting it another way - the two PCs may be running the same version of Python, but are they importing from the same file?